# Secondary display DisplayMetrics dependent on primary display?

Tags: android

I have two different tablets:

- 10.1" tablet - 1280x800 @ ~149dpi
- 15.6" tablet - 1920x1080 @ ~156dpi

These tablets are both very close to 160dpi (where `1px` is equivalent to `1dp`) in terms of actual physical (real-world) specifications. The system reports them as being *exactly* 160dpi. That's fine, no big deal here.

I also have a secondary display. It has the same physical (real-world) specifications as my 10.1" tablet. However, when I connect it to the two different tablets and use it to display an Android `Presentation`, the secondary display will report wildly different `DisplayMetrics`.

When connected to the 10.1" tablet, the secondary display reports:

- Resolution: 1280x800
- DPI: 237.0
- Density: 1.48125

When connected to the 15.6" tablet, the secondary display reports:

- Resolution: 1024x768
- DPI: 227.0
- Density: 1.41875

What could cause this?

---

The app itself is dumb as rocks. All I do is create a `Presentation` object and show a dummy checkerboard layout on both the primary and secondary displays.

I've tried using both the `MediaRouter` and `DisplayManager` APIs for finding my `Display` and creating my `Presentation`. They both give identical results.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    MediaRouter mediaRouter = (MediaRouter) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_ROUTER_SERVICE);
    MediaRouter.RouteInfo route = mediaRouter.getSelectedRoute(MediaRouter.ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO);

    if (route != null) {
        Display display = route.getPresentationDisplay();
        if (display != null) {
            Presentation presentation = new MyPresentation(this, display);
            presentation.show();
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    DisplayManager manager = (DisplayManager) getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
    Display[] displays = manager.getDisplays(DisplayManager.DISPLAY_CATEGORY_PRESENTATION);

    if (displays.length > 0) {
        Presentation presentation = new MyPresentation(this, displays[0]);
        presentation.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you connecting the tablets to the secondary display? If you actually display something from the 15.6" tablet on the secondary display, does it fill the screen? What sort of secondary display is this? (LCD panel? projector? something else?) And... who makes a 15.6" Android tablet? :-)

Comment: The secondary display is connected via USB + HDMI. When I display things on the secondary display, they appear larger than they should (because the density is higher than it ought to be) but the screen is filled (i.e. all pixels are on). The secondary display is an LCD panel.

Comment: My best guess is it's something strange with the manufacturer of the 15.6" tablet and its HDMI connection. You might try experimenting hooking it up to other devices (monitor, TV, etc.) and see how it reacts. It may have poor ability to detect the native resolution of the external display and falls back to another mode (XGA resolution in your case). And... **who makes a 15.6" Android tablet?** :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare checkout Samsung's Galaxy View, I think it's 18.4''

Comment: @jackz314: True, though that's no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a VirtualDisplay from physical display.
When you create a VirtualDisplay, you can change density dpi.

```
displayManager.createVirtualDisplay(
      "VirtualDisplay",
      virtualDisplayWidth,
      virtualDisplayHeight,
      designedDensityDpi,
      surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface(),
      VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PRESENTATION
    );
```